# How to get the value from li element in query

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, tooltip

xhtml:

```
<ul class="groupsWrapper">
    <ui:repeat value="#{connectDashBoardBean.groups}" var="group">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{group.activeGroup}">
            <li class="group titleToolTip chooseSubGroup" title="Click To Choose">
                <div style="display: none;" class="groupId">#{group.groupId}</div>
                <div class="groupContainer">
                    <div class="groupImage" style="float:left;color: #fff">
                        <h:graphicImage value="#{group.groupIconPath}" height="70" width="70"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="groupContent" style="display:inline-block;padding: 0;word-wrap: break-word;font-weight: bold;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{group.groupName}"/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="groupTotalSubGroup" style="display:block;padding: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                        <h:outputText value="Sub Group:#{group.totalSubGroup}"/>
                    </div> -->
                    <div class="groupFollower" style="display:block;padding: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                        <h:outputText value="Followers:#{group.totalFollower}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="activeThread" style="display:block;padding: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                        <h:outputText value="Active Thread:#{group.totalActiveThread}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ui:fragment>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
var group = $(this).find('.groupId').text();
```

is returning me empty always, I tried with `text()`, `html()` and `val()`

I am using this selector inside `.tooltipster()` of ajax call

```
$('.chooseSubGroup').tooltipster({

    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function (origin, continueTooltip) {

        // we'll make this function asynchronous and allow the
        // tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification
        // while fetching our data
        continueTooltip();

        // next, we want to check if our data has already been
        // cached
        if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            var group = $(this).find('.groupId').text();
            alert(group);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'tooltip/sub_group_tooltip.xhtml?groupId=' + group,
                data: {
                    groupId: group
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // update our tooltip content with our returned
                    // data and cache it
                    origin.tooltipster('update', data).data('ajax',
                        'cached');
                }
            });
        }
    },
    interactive: true,
    interactiveTolerance: 350,
    onlyOne: true,
    theme: '.tooltip-theme',
    trigger: 'click',
    updateAnimation: true,
    arrow: true,
    position: 'right',
    delay: 500
});
```

Please let me know how I will get the value of hidden div?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, based on your code, I don't see anything that could be wrong. Can you please `console.log($(this))` and tell me what is returned?

Comment: JSF is irrelevant in this question. jQuery doesn't work with JSF. Instead, it works with JSF-generated HTML output. In order to generate better answers from `[jquery]` users, you should remove the irrelevant JSF information from the question and replace it by JSF-generated HTML output (and replace `[jsf-2]` tag by `[html]`).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I tried with console log, out put:[Object {animation="fade", arrow=true, ...}], which is nothing but giving the properties of tooltip.may be its not dictating the <li> element, any work around for this?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Thank you for the point, Now for time being I applied the work around like :var groupId; and $('.chooseSubGroup').click(function() {
groupId = $(this).find('.groupId').text();
}); and finally using that variable in tooltip function, any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltip is returning it's object as `$(this)`. The workaround would be

```
$('.chooseSubGroup').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.tooltipster({
        //other code
        if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
        var group = $this.find('.groupId').text();  //note, $this, not $(this)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

origin.attr("id")  link_*_*_>
http://forum.nickstakenburg.com/index.php?p=/discussion/2596/how-to-do-ajax-tooltip/p1